# Angular Displaying a Message for 5 Seconds

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I need to display a message for 5 seconds and then it should disappear. I'm using Fuse Messages and could not succeed on showing then hiding the message. Here is my code below. What should I do and what am I doing wrong?

TS:

```
  if (koliList.length == 1) {
    if (this.addPackage(koliList[0], frmControlKoliBarkod) == false) {
      let message = this._messages.Show("Transaction is Successful", "WARNING", 5);
      setTimeout(() => {
        message;
      }, 5000);
      return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: what's the error in console?

Comment: i don't get any errors

Comment: fuse message not have a property `autohideduration` or 'hideDelay` or something like these? else sure you can indicate how hide the message (it's the instruction you need write under the setTimeout). Read the docs about the component (sorry I can not find the link)

Answer (score 1):

make following changes in code.

`setTimeout(() => { this.message=""; }, 5000); return this.message;`

This will set message to empty string after 5 seconds.